# Where did synth-pop and electro-pop come from, and what it's difference?

Tags: terminology, genre

I recognize that they're both using synthesizer on their songs, that I think that they're came from the same roots, but nowadays they likely to expand their type.

For example, I define *The 1975* (band) is a mix of synth-pop and rock, but *Au Revoir, Simone* (band) is kinda electro-pop that likely to synth-pop.

So:

1. Is it correct that both genre came from the same roots?
2. What's the difference between those genres?

Answer (score 4):

*Synth Pop* really just means any pop music that is oriented around synthesizer sounds. It's a broad term and most synth pop bands could also be labelled with another more specific genre such as *dream pop*, *new wave*, *new romantic* or so on. You could argue that synth pop in the widest sense doesn't culturally 'come from' anywhere apart from the increasing availability of synthesizers from the 70s onwards.

The term '*Electro*' on its own most usually refers to the crossover between early electronic pop music such as Kraftwerk, American DJ-oriented hip-hop and disco cultures, and funk music. One example is Herbie Hancock's *Rockit*. Another is Afrika Bambaataa & the Soulsonic Force's *Planet Rock*, which features robotic voices and an emphasised harsh electronic sound.

As for *"Electro-Pop"* - I don't think that term is widely understood to mean anything very specific. You might notice that *Au Revoir, Simone* aren't labelled as 'Electro-Pop' in their Wikipedia article, while referenced artists in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electropop include Britney Spears, LMFAO, and Taio Cruz. It could be just a synonym for 'synth-pop', though it's somewhat redundant these days to say that, as electronic instrumentation is so common. It could also refer to a pop act that references the gritty early 'electro' sound (Such as techno artists do in the 'electroclash' genre).