# What genre is CHVRCHES?

Tags: pop

I can't tell if CHVRCHES is pop or electro. It seems like some songs would be for the radio, but some songs by them are more for dancing and I can't decide on what exact genre they are.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but relevant to what 'electro' means : http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/479/where-did-synth-pop-and-electro-pop-come-from-and-what-its-difference

Comment: Your question also inspired http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/2732/what-is-pop-music !

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/2733/16) to another question states - and I would agree - that it's possible for a song or band to be 'pop' *and* belong to another more specific genre at the same time. As to that more specific label, I don't think 'electro' is necessarily a good fit for Chvrches as it refers specifically to a style of electronic funk originating in the early 80's. (It's also used to describe acts who work in other styles, but not in a way that seems to have found broad agreement). 'Electronic', on the other hand, is a much more general term that would be appropriate.

Although it's another broad genre, **synth-pop** seems perfect for Chvrches if you need a single label.

Answer (score 0):

Synth-pop // Indietronica // Indie-pop

It's indie for sure, mixed with electro synths influences.

Comment: Hi! Your answer is probably correct, but it has been marked as Low Quality by the system, due to it's lack of content. It would be nice to expand your answer with links of songs, sources...